# Error when importing ggplot bubble chart into Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am having some trouble with Shiny and ggplot

When I run the following code to produce a bubble chart in Shiny I am getting this error message :

"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "value", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3"

But when I run it outside it is fine

Any idea?

Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

gtest = data.frame(cbind(sort(rep(c(1:3),5)),rep(c(1:5),3),sample(-8:8, 15)/10))


# Define a server for the Shiny app
server <- function(input, output) {

  g3 <- reactive({
    g2 <- gtest[gtest[2]==input$article,]
    g2 <-g2[order(g2[3],decreasing = TRUE), ]
    g2 <- rbind(g2[g2[1]==input$article,], g2[!g2[1]==input$article,])
    angl <-seq(0, 360, length.out =(nrow(g2)))
    angl <-angl[1:(length(angl)-1)]
    g2[3] <-(max(g2[3])-min(g2[3]))*.3+(max(g2[3])-g2[3])
    x<-c(0,g2[2:nrow(g2),3]*cos(angl%*%(pi/180)))
    y<-c(0,g2[2:nrow(g2),3]*round(sin((pi/180)*angl),2))
    g2<-cbind(g2,x,y)
    colnames(g2) <- c("col1","col2","value","x","y")
    g2
  })

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot

  output$g3plot = renderPlot({
    p<-ggplot(g3(),aes(x,y,label= col1))+
      geom_point(colour="white", fill="red", shape=21, size = 20)+
      geom_text(size=5)+
      theme_bw()
    print(p)
  })
}

#runApp("R/Test_shiny")

# Define the overall UI
ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Articles by similarities"),
  sidebarLayout(      
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("article", "Article:", choice=unique(gtest[2]))), hr()),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("g3plot")
  )   
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems to run from my side:
[image]

I thus modified the following row:

```
x<-c(0,g2[2:nrow(g2),3]*cos(angl*(pi/180)))
```

Regards